# Mongo find value with unknown parent key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking for a value in a Mongo table where its parent key might not have a descriptive or known name. Here is an example of what one of our documents looks like.

```
    { 
       "assetsId": {
         "0": "546cf2f8585ffa451bb68369" 
      },
       "slotTypes": {
         "0": { "usage": "json" },
         "1":  { "usage": "image" }
      }
    }
```

I am looking to see if this contains "usage": "json" in slotTypes, but I can't guarantee that the parent key for this usage will be "0".

I tried using the following query without any luck:

```
db.documents.find(
   {
     slotTypes:
       {
          $elemMatch:
            {
               "usage": "json"
            }
       }
    }
)
```

Sorry in advance if this is a really basic question, but I'm not used to working in a nosql database.

Comment: No. it is not possible. It would be possible if the `slotTypes` were an array.

Comment: U can use full-text-search

Comment: I would really like to stay away from a full text search. Doing that seems kind of hacky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure you're going to be able to solve elegantly this with your current schema; `slotTypes` should be an array of sub-documents, which would allow your `$elemMatch` query to work. Right now, it's an object with numeric-ish keys.

That is, your document schema should be something like:

```
{
   "assetsId": {
     "0": "546cf2f8585ffa451bb68369"
  },
   "slotTypes": [
     { "usage": "json" },
     { "usage": "image" }
  ]
}
```

If changing the data layout isn't an option, then you're going to need to basically scan through every document to find matches with `$where`. This is slow, unindexable, and awkward.

```
db.objects.find({$where: function() {
  for(var key in this.slotTypes) {
    if (this.slotTypes[key].usage == "json") return true;
  }
  return false;
}})
```

You should read the [documentation on $where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) to make sure you understand the caveats of it, and for the love of all that is holy, sanitize your inputs to the function; this is live code that is executing in the context of your database.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I agree with you, these slotTypes should have been put into an array, but this is one of those situations where I am going to war with the army I have, not the one I want. When I run The script you gave me I get no results.

Comment: Make sure you're running it on the right collection. I ran it locally against your test document and it found it just fine.

Comment: Sorry, there I misspelled the table name, that did work.

Comment: @ChrisHeald - how abt when the parent key is unknown ?